# Getting error while creating trigger- PL/SQL: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Tags: oracle

I am creating a trigger in which I want to update fields from another table.
Please see below trigger which I have written:

```
create or replace
 TRIGGER RE_SE_INSERT
 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON USER FOR EACH ROW

 BEGIN
 update user set 
 :new.ci_No = (select ci_No from customer where ci_id = :new.ci_id),
 :new.ci_name = (select ci_name from customer where ci_id = :new.ci_id),
 :new.IS_deleted = (select deleted from customer where ci_id = :new.ci_id);

 END;
```

I have checked for the column name whether they are wrong but all the column name are correct as per the table but still I get `ORA-01747 error of invalid table.column`.

Could you please help me here?

Thanks in advance!
Tapan

Comment: :Does it make sense to update the column `after insert or update`,i think no ,and it will be better if you change trigger to Before update /insert trigger.No need for `Update user set` inside trigger ,and rather than writing query for each column ,create a cursor that fetch all the values from customer table for the same ci_id

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. I am new in Database coyuld you please help me how to write cursor  on trigger level. I would be great help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 create or replace trigger RE_SE_INSERT
 BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE  --create a BEFORE insert/update trigger
 ON USER FOR EACH ROW
 DECLARE
  CURSOR new_cur
  IS 
    SELECT ci_no
          ,ci_name
          ,deleted
     FROM customer
     where ci_id = :new.ci_id;
   new_row  new_cur%ROWTYPE;
 BEGIN
  --update user set   --remove this statement
  OPEN new_cur;
  FETCH new_cur INTO new_row;
   IF new_cur%FOUND THEN
    :new.ci_No      := new_row.ci_no;
    :new.ci_name    := new_row.ci_name;
    :new.IS_deleted := new_row.deleted;
   END IF;
  CLOSE new_cur;

END RE_SE_INSERT;
/
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a `CURSOR FOR-LOOP`?

Comment: @Armunin: It depend on person to person and on some requirement that may come in future ,suppose this trigger need to be enhanced in future and different value based on insert or update event ,then a cursor that can be reused should be implemented ,it doesnt make any difference in performance .

Comment: It's not making a difference in performance but in readability. And what is the difference in reusability? You can reuse the `FOR-LOOP` the same way, that you do with a fetching

Comment: @Armunin: `resue` means, i can open the cursor twice in the same trigger ,when i want to with the same declaration.Again i say ,it depend on person to person.Please let me know if you not clear:)

Comment: I totally agree that it's depending on ones personal liking. I am just curious to know whether there are other reasons. I am always trying to learn something new :) And you can reuse the `FOR-LOOP` the same way multiple times as you can with opening and fetching a cursor. But with less lines of code and therefore less chances to build in errors ;)

Comment: @Armunin:True ! with less code and quality code,but if you really want to learn something new ,refer this link  [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27045/why-use-explicit-cursors-instead-of-regular-loops)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42596/discussion-between-armunin-and-gaurav-soni)

Comment: @Gaurav: I have used the same trigger which you have written above but its giving me an error while compliing. In last 4 lines new.IS_deleted = new_row.deleted; END IF; CLOSE new_cur; END RE_SE_INSERT; errors related to encounterd an symbol ";" and "=" COuld you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user2742651:I have edited the answer , actually assignment in plsql is `:=` not `=`

Comment: @Gaurav: Thank you so much. I have also tried to write trigger as another way without using cursor and update statement and it works. It is working as per requirement